# test class for DOM.XMLNode response in HTTPcallouts in post method

Tags: apex, unit-test, soap-api, callout, xml

How can I write a test class with DOM.XMLNode response?

```
request.setBody('<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><Header/><Body><login xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"><username>' + '<userName>' + '</username><password>' + '<Password>' + '</password></login></Body></Envelope>');
    Dom.XmlNode resultElmt = (new Http()).send(request).getBodyDocument().getRootElement()
            .getChildElement('Body','http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')
            .getChildElement('loginResponse','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com')
            .getChildElement('result','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com');

    String sessionId = resultElmt.getChildElement('sessionId','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com').getText();
```

Test class from comment:

```
@IsTest 
global class Stubby implements HttpCalloutMock { 
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) { 
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Dom.Document doc = res.getBodyDocument();
        Dom.XMLNode address = doc.getRootElement();
        String name = address.getChildElement('serverUrl', null).getText();
        String SESSION_ID = address.getChildElement('SESSION_ID', null).getText();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are doing a raw [HTTP HttpRequest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http.htm) to the Partner API to establish a Session. In this case you create the test using an [HttpCalloutMock](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm).

With you Http Mock you can return whatever HTTPResponse you need.

A sample SOAP envelope response from the login method is available in [PartnerLogin](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PartnerLogin).

---

Your class that implements HttpCalloutMock needs to return the HttpResponse with a body that would otherwise come from the real service.

```
    string sessionBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
'<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"' +
  'xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"' +
  'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">' +
  '<soapenv:Body>' +
     '<loginResponse>' +
        '<result>' +
           '<passwordExpired>false</passwordExpired>' +
           '<serverUrl>https://na1.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/10.0</serverUrl>' +
           '<sessionId>QwWsHJyTPW.1pd0_jXlNKOSU</sessionId>' +
           '<userId>005D0000000nVYVIA2</userId>' +
           '<userInfo>' +
              '<!-- ... -->' +
           '</userInfo>' +
        '</result>' +
     '</loginResponse>' +
  '</soapenv:Body>' +
'</soapenv:Envelope>';

    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
    res.setBody(sessionBody);
    res.setStatusCode(200);
    return res;
```

Comment: Hi Daniel,  I have added this code for HTTPRequest callouts. Please suggest what I need to do else?@IsTest global class Stubby implements HttpCalloutMock {
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
            HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
       Dom.Document doc = res.getBodyDocument();
        Dom.XMLNode address = doc.getRootElement();
         String name = address.getChildElement('serverUrl', null).getText();
          String  SESSION_ID = address.getChildElement('SESSION_ID', null).getText();  }

Comment: @oookkk You need to include the expected SOAP response. Or at least enough of it so you can test parse the `SessionId` and `ServerUrl` out of it.

Comment: Hi Daniel,   Do I need to include (string )session body of SOAP response in my test class that you have mentioned ?

Comment: how can we parse this SOAP response in order to check in test class?

Comment: @oookkk Honestly, you seem to be doing it the hard way by manually creating and parsing the SOAP response. I created an [alternative version of wsdl2apex](http://www.fishofprey.com/2014/11/dreamforce-2014-presentation-improved.html) that will let you just import the login method. It can even generate the test class for coverage and the mock for you if needed.

Comment: @Daniel..So is there any workaround with my approach?

Comment: @oookkk If you are moving raw SOAP messages you will need to use the Apex [XML support](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_xml_support.htm). The tool I linked to can generate an XML DOM based parser for you from the WSDL.